# SSO not working for multiple applications with MFA using custom polices

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, multi-factor-authentication

We have multiple Angular SPA using same application (client Id) in B2C. We have implemented custom policies for user flow - MFA using phone or email option that is invoked in each applications independently.

We want to achieve SSO between applications i.e if Application A logs in successfully and user tries to open Application B it should automatically be logged in.

With the below SSO configuration in custom polices we are able to bypass the login screen when Application B is accessed in the browser but the user is not able to pass through the MFA and is always presented with MFA screen even after the user has already logged in with Application A.

```xml
<UserJourneyBehaviors> 
     <SingleSignOn Scope="Tenant" KeepAliveInDays="7" /> 
     <SessionExpiryType>Rolling</SessionExpiryType> 
     <SessionExpiryInSeconds>86400</SessionExpiryInSeconds> 
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

Not sure if any additional settings is required to bypass MFA.

I have also tried playing with Preconditions to check on 'isActiveMFASession' and skip the MFA journey but not able to get it working. We have below Orchestration steps.

```xml
<UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInMFAOption" DefaultCpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <!-- <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange"/> -->
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <!-- <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH"/> -->
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!--Sample: If uses is enrolled for MFA, ask the user to select the preferred method-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
         <Preconditions>
           <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isActiveMFASession</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
        </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        
         <!-- Throw error if control was bypassed -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="Return-MFA-Method-Incorrect-Error">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail</Value>
              <Value>email</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail</Value>
              <Value>phone</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Phone verification: If MFA is not required, the next three steps (#5-#7) should be removed.
             This step checks whether there's a phone number on record,  for the user. If found, then the user is challenged to verify it. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
           <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isActiveMFASession</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <!--Sample: If the preferred MFA method is not 'phone' skip this orchestration step-->
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail</Value>
              <Value>phone</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>        
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PhoneFactor-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Save MFA phone number: The precondition verifies whether the user provided a new number in the 
             previous step. If so, then the phone number is stored in the directory for future authentication 
             requests. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>newPhoneNumberEntered</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWriteWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!--Sample: MFA with email-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail</Value>
              <Value>email</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="Email-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerifyOnSignIn" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
```

I have also tried to read the documentation for SM-AAD and SM-MFA but not much luck on how to integrate with my policies.

Any help on giving the right direction to make this work is highly appreciated.

Update 1 :

I am able to make SSO work but If I logout of any of the application it is not asking me to select the option either Phone or Email for MFA and defaulting me to the last selected one when the user tries to login.

Is it because of the claims I have set for extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail?

I have an orchestration step to skip it in first place for achieving SSO

```
 <!--Sample: If uses is enrolled for MFA, ask the user to select the preferred method-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
         <Preconditions> 
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail</Value> 
               <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action> 
            </Precondition> 
         </Preconditions> 
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

And even Single Sign out is not working i.e If I logout of one application there is an active session for another application.

Can you please help me inresolving the issue , I tried playing with the preconditions but if I remove the above claim my SSO doesn't work in first place.

Comment: Have you tried single sign out - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#single-sign-out

Comment: Yes , SM-jwt-issuer is already included in JwtIssuer Technical Profile but how can I add URL to Front-channel logout URL as I have 2-3 different logout URL's as it is having just an option to add One : 
http://abc.1.com
http://def.2.com

Comment: We are using same application registered in b2c for 3-4 different SPA , how can we add multiple logout url's @rbrayb?

Comment: You can't - it only allows one.

Comment: okay, any specific reason you can point for persisting the extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail claim for subsequent login after adding precondition for extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail? It defaults user to previously selected option either phone or email rather than providing an option to select it

Comment: Exactly - you've selected the option and it would be a pain to have to select it each time. To change at a later point, see https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone

Answer (score 0):

To get SSO across the whole journey, you need to use the same SM for each step.

I usually make a new SM that combines SM-AAD and SM-MFA and then use that.

Comment: I have edited the question and added an Update 1 section , can you please help me on that?